# How do you map an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array

```
K = {"a", "b", "b"};
V = {"1", "2", "3"};
```

from these two array I want to got the result like this

```
$display = "a: 1; b: 2; c: 3;"
echo $display;
```

output

```
"a: 1; b: 2; c: 3;"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to merge them?

```
$display = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($K); $i++)
{
    $display .= $K[$i] . ": " . $V[$i] . "; ";
}
```

Something like that. I didn't use PHP in a while.

Comment: yes,LukeN,just simple , that I could not found , thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to move the call to `count($K)` out of your for loop condition.  It's going to count the size of the array once every time it evaluates the condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_map()` to do this:

```
<?php

function combine($k, $v)
{
  return "$k: $v";
}

$K = array("a", "b", "c");
$V = array("1", "2", "3");

$display = implode(", ", array_map("combine", $K, $V));
```

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Use this, there is an example for exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

why not just store the array as an associative array to begin with so you don't have to combine them later on. e.g.,

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);  
foreach($arr as $k => $v)    
    echo "$k: $v; ";
```

or if you have to have two separate arrays and combine them use php's internal array_combine function. e.g.,

```
$k = array('a','b','c');  
$v = array(1,2,3);  
$result = array_combine($k,$v);  
foreach($result as $k => $v)  
    echo "$k: $v; ";
```